# Getting velocity from IMU acceleration

Tags: imu

I am doing to research about why you cannot use IMU acceleration the integrate to get velocity.  Everyone says you cannot do that due to there being error but what error is this exactly and where does it come from?

Comment: See [the answer by JMarple](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/7820/37) on [Displacement with accelerometer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/7816/37)

Comment: @MarkBooth This isn't really a duplicate. The question is about why the error makes it difficult to integrate accelerometers. The answer you linked only says how to integrate accelerometers but is still incorrect because the change in time is left out of his equation anyway.

Comment: Whether a question is a duplicate or not @cBEiN is not whether the question is the same, it's whether it can be answered with the same answer. In this case, this question is answered by the [specific answer](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/7820/37) I linked to: "any drift/error/noise on the accelerometer gets doubled integrated and your positional error will grow quadratically".

Comment: @MarkBooth But, the question you linked is also marked as a duplicate, which is confusing, and both of the duplicate questions are different than this question. Regardless, the specific answer you linked in the comment mentions only part of the questions asked here. So many questions seem to be put on hold because they are not "clear" enough or are a "duplicate". This discourages me to participate. Questions in robotics are sometimes difficult to present due to the nature of robotics in general. I only say any of this because I want the beta to be successful.

Comment: As asked @cBEiN, the linked answer does answer this question. If you feel that the answer you are looking for isn't then please submit your own question. Remember that on *Robotics*, we prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you currently understand, and what you don't understand. Also, please take a look at the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to help write a good question.